# Combine the output of two ls commands divided by a ; (semicolon)

Tags: linux, ls

I've been trying and looking at all sorts commands but can't seem to find the correct syntax;

I want to combine the output of two `ls` commands divided by a `;` (semicolon) and write the output to a file.

My ls commands are:

```
ls *.lst
ls -d -1 $PWD/*.lst
```

It should look like:

```
filename1.lst; /tmp/filename1.lst
```

and the output line should be added to a textfile called files.dat (`> files.dat`?)

Comment: Do you want to append `>>` or overwrite `>` to files.dat?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could try

```
echo "$(command1); $(command2)"
```

Comment: it kind of does but I really need it to do filename.lst;/tmp/filename1.lst so two ls output lines per line separated by a ;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find $(pwd) -name '*.lst' -printf '%f; %p\n' >>files.dat
```

added (appended) to the files.dat.

Comment: this one generates an error (find: -printf: unknown option) or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your platform's find does not implement -printf operator

Comment: i'm testing it on macosx (sh & bash)but it needs to run on redhat linux

Comment: I haven't got a redhat installation at the moment

Comment: This will work on both `ls *.lst |while read f; do echo "$f; $PWD/$f"; done`, but the first will work on a linux system

Comment: Thats it, only thing left to do is remove the space after the semicolon:-)

Comment: Awesome that you've helped me out so fast, now I can go creating my script:-)

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for could be accomplished by `paste`.

```
 FILE1="$(mktemp)"
 ls *.lst > $FILE1
 ls -d -1 *.lst | paste -d ";" $FILE1 - >> files.dat
```

BTW `$PWD` is the current directory so `$PWD/something` would be the same as writing just `something`.